# Is it possible to share a dual monitor USB C Hub with two M2 Macbooks Pros?

Tags: usb, kvm

I have 2 Macbooks Pro with M2 processor and want to improve my setup. I have a dual monitor USB C Hub similar to this:
[image]

and wondering if it is possible to connect it with a female-female USB C thingy:

[image]

to a USB C KVM switch:

[image]

And share the 2 monitors to the 2 Macbooks. This works?

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if it is possible to connect it with a female-female USB C thingy

It may be possible but NOT RECOMMENDED.

In the USB-C spec they lay out how the cables and adapters are to work, and specify that anything deviating from this spec can introduce hazards.  Part of the reason they don't allow the adapters shown in the spec is because there's complications on indicating the capability of the cables and devices when such an adapter is in the chain.

The USB-C spec requires cables, devices, and adapters to indicate it's capabilities to the host by means of a resistor network or a small integrated circuit.  This indicates the protocols supported (such as in the case of a video adapter) or what is a safe voltage and current (such as with a power supply).  There are USB-C hubs that will have female USB-C ports and allow connecting a video adapter to a MacBook but they also have a bunch of electronics in them to make sure that there's no attempt to put a 5 volt 3 amp cable with a power supply that is supplying 48 volts at 5 amps.  If the user of such an adapter is aware of how the rules work and why they are in place, and follows them without fail, then it would be possible to use such an adapter safely.  Break the rules once, and in the wrong way, then it could destroy a very expensive MacBook.

The issue of shorting out some USB-C devices is but one concern, and given the damage it could do the far larger concern.  The other concern is that I recall that MacOS doesn't support two independent displays from a single USB-C port.

Note that I specified ***independent*** displays.  A common result of using dual display adapters with Mac computers is that both displays show the same image.  For some people this is the desired function.  My guess is that the desired function is to get an extended desktop, and Apple does not support this.

Note that I specified ***Apple*** does not support this.  I've seen with people that installed Windows or Linux on Intel/Apple computers that they could get two independent displays working from a single USB-C port, and it is fairly trivial to find examples.  Also possible is using some non-Apple drivers inside Mac OS to achieve this function, but finding examples of that will be more difficult to find since an update to the OS often breaks this function so searches for any reports of success tend to be lost in the reports of failures.

I've seen that people got Linux to run on the Apple silicon Macs so I guess it is possible to run Linux to get the dual display mode to work, and then run a virtual machine on Linux for running MacOS.  That's an involved process, and likely quite fragile given how new this software is right now.

This doesn't mean it is impossible to connect two independent displays to two Macs by a KVM.  What it means is connecting the KVM to the Macs by two (or maybe three) USB-C cables, and likely some kind of dock or adapter to the KVM switch.  There can be quite a discussion on how to best connect the displays and KVM but the basics is pretty trivial and straightforward, choose an appropriate KVM switch then get the appropriate cables to make the connections to the MacBooks.  What is appropriate depends on the specific capabilities of the MacBooks, the capabilities of the displays, and how the person that has to fund this wishes to balance cost to convenience.

If you absolutely, positively, must have a single USB-C cable to each MacBook for power, USB, and two independent displays, then that is likely possible.  Making that work though is not something Apple supports and so would be far from trivial.